# Qt plugin initialization failure upon starting Windows application

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, conan, qt6

I could not start this simple startup code.

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  return app.exec();
}
```

The following popup appears:

[image: Error message]

The bin folder looks like this:

[image: Folder structure]

I build the project with the following Conan script:

```
...
    options = {'qt6': 'ANY'}
    default_options = {'qt:shared': True, 'qt6': None}
    generators = 'cmake', 'cmake_paths', 'cmake_find_package', 'cmake_find_package_multi'
    requires = 'qt/6.2.2'
...
```

My CMakeLists.txt is the following:

```
...
# Find Qt package.
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core)

# Find includes in the build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)

# Turn on automatic invocation of the MOC, UIC & RCC
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

# Link the thirdparties.
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Core) 
...
```

May I ask a suggestion what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Qt app deployment for Windows documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). More specifically, do you have a `platforms/qwindows.dll` file?

Comment: I thought conan installs the dependencies automatically... Because if it's so difficult to even create a simple application in Qt, I will use wxWidgets instead...